# Email OTP authentication fails with SaaS Service Provider in WSO2 Identity Server 5.10

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 IS 5.10 as the auth server for multi-tenant app.  I have configured a Service Provider in the WSO2 IS super tenant and marked it as "SaaS".  For each tenant, I create a new tenant in WSO2 IS and create users and roles there.

With plain OIDC, this works just fine.  I configure my application with the client ID for the SaaS service provider, and I can log in as user@tenant.com and the claims in my token are just what I'd expect.

However, when I configure MFA with Email OTP, as described [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/configuring-email-otp), I see the initial login screen, see the OTP screen, get the OTP, enter the OTP, and then I get:

```
Authentication attempt failed.
One or more read-only claim is missing in the requested claim set. Please contact your administrator for more information about this issue.
```

I can't find anything that seems relevant in the WSO2 logs.

It works correctly with a user created in the super tenant, or when the service provider and Email OTP identify provider are configured in the tenant where the the user is, but I can't do this, since my application needs to authenticate users from multiple tenants.

Interestingly, if there is a user with the same name in both the tenant and the super tenant, authentication succeeds, but when I inspect the access token, I see that the subject is user@carbon.super, not user@tenant.com.

Comment: Hi Stephen, 

I'm also facing the same issue now. Is there any fix you found?

Comment: No progress.  I plan to put together a repro using WSO2 sample apps so I can do a proper bug report, but haven't done that yet.   If I do learn anything, I'll update here.

Comment: Stephan - This is an issue with the product and I have created an issue on Jira for the same. Please follow this link - https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/11172